# Prove or disprove that $\sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\left|\sum_{\substack{d|n \\d<Q}}\mu(d)\right|\sim\pi(Q)$

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, asymptotics

To begin, let us set

$$A_Q(n):=\sum_{d|n \\ d<Q}\mu(d)$$

If we fix $Q$ and let $n$ vary, we get a very surprising amount of cancellation. For instance, the trivial bound

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\left[|A_Q(n)|\right]&\leq\mathbb{E}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\left[\sum_{\substack{d|n \\ d<Q}}1\right]\\
&=\sum_{d=1}^{Q-1}\frac{1}{d}\sim\log(Q)
\end{align*}

can be reduced to the (astonishing) $\mathbb{E}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}[|A_Q(n)|]=O(1)$, and even more strongly $\mathbb{E}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}[|A_Q(n)|^2]=O(1)$. The question now turns the exact nature of the distribution of $A_Q(n)$ over $\mathbb{N}$ as $Q$ varies.

On the "maximum" side of things, the only trivial bound is using Sperner's Lemma which yields the inequality

$$\sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}|A_Q(n)|\leq {\pi(Q)\choose \pi(Q)/2}\leq \frac{2^{\pi(Q)}}{\sqrt{\pi(Q)}}$$

Stronger results require finer knowledge of the distribution of primes, and more specifically getting a large value $A_Q(n)$ means that the prime factors of $n$ are tightly packed and so large values of $A_Q(n)$ are morally equivalent to repeated small prime gaps (i.e a reltively small interval $M$ in which many primes appear). While proving any results seem difficult, numerical evidence suggests the following miraculous asymptotic relationship

$$\sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}|A_Q(n)|\sim_{Q\to\infty}\pi(Q)$$

There are other seemingly miraculous properties of $A_Q(n)$, like the fact that the probabilities $\Pr_{n\in\mathbb{N}}[A_Q(n)=j]$ seem to converge as $Q\to\infty$ for any $j$, but  that is a different can of worms entirely.

If somebody could give any insights about how someone would even try to go about proving $\sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}|A_Q(n)|\sim_{Q\to\infty}\pi(Q)$ I would be extremely grateful, since currently all of my approaches seem to only result in weak upper bounds.

Comment: $A_Q(\prod_{p\in (Q^{1/2},Q)} p) = 1-(\pi(Q-1)-\pi(Q^{1/2}))$

Comment: *the only trivial bound is using Sperner's Lemma...* I would say "the most trivial bound is $Q$: at most $Q$ terms each of which is at most $1$". The bound $\pi(Q)$ is, of course not so immediate...

Comment: @fedja are you sure about that? The $\pi(Q)$ comes from the fact that the sum $\sum_{\substack{d|n \\ d<Q}}\mu(d)$ is a sum over $2^{\pi(Q)}$ points, for quite immediate reasons...

Comment: @MiloMoses Then I just don't understand your notation: I thought that $d<Q$ means $d\in[1,2,\dots,Q]$ and $\pi(Q)$ is the usual prime counting function, but, apparently, you mean something else. What is it then?

Comment: @fedja The notation you assumed I am using is correct. The bound $Q$ is immediate, I agree, but the bound $\frac{2^{\pi(Q)}}{\sqrt{\pi(Q)}}$ was used instead to illustrate a bound which uses properties of the Mobius function, even if it is less sharp. By "The bound $\pi(Q)$ is, of course not so immediate" I thought you were referring to the bound $\frac{2^{\pi(Q)}}{\sqrt{\pi(Q)}}$ as the "bound based on $\pi(Q)$", but I see now that that was a misunderstanding.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is not true.  In fact
$$ 
x(\log x)^{-1+1/\pi}  \gg \sup_n \Big| \sum_{\substack{ d|n \\ d\le x}} \mu(d) \Big| \gg x (\log x)^{-1+1/\pi}. 
$$
The upper bound is due to [Montgomery and Vaughan](https://deepblue.lib.umich.edu/bitstream/handle/2027.42/43188/10998_2004_Article_400315.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y) (see Theorem 5 there) and the lower bound is due to Hall and Tenenbaum (see the references in Montgomery and Vaughan).

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH for this reference!!!!!!!

Comment: Hi, do you know if [this is well-known](https://mathoverflow.net/a/388696/84768), that $f(x)-\sum_{\Im(\rho)>0} e^{i\rho x}$ is analytic at $0$ for some "elementary" function $f$, it should give non-obvious information on the distributions of non-trivial zeros. Also the expression seems to be continuous in $\epsilon$ when replacing $\zeta(s)$ by $\zeta(s)+\epsilon L(s,\chi)$, which is surprising.